# Returning a string with characters removed in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I have this code where, given an input string, I'm trying to return an output string with the characters removed.
The input string must end with a full stop and the output string must also end with a full stop. What I am really struggling with is how to parse individual characters in my input string and processing them in the loop.
I keep getting various errors related to boundaries and out of range addresses. Any help would be much appreciated, as I am relatively new to the language. Thanks!

```
.data 

  string: .asciiz "COMP30080."
  stop: .word 46    
  three: .word 51    
  output: .asciiz ""    
  digit_found: .asciiz "Digit found!"

.text     
.globl main

  main: 

    la $t0, string    
    lw $a0, 0($t0)    
    la $t3, stop    
    jal numberExtract    
    sw $v0, output

    li $v0, 10    
    syscall 

  .globl numberExtract

  numberExtract:    
    beq $t3, $t0, numberExtractEnd    
    lb $t0, 0($a0)    
    li $t1, 53    
    beq $t0, $t1, digit     
    sw $t0, ($v0)
    addi $v0, $v0, 4    
    addi $a0, $a0, 1    
    j numberExtract      
  digit:    
    li $v0, 4    
    syscall     
    la $a0, digit_found    
    li $v0, 4    
    syscall     
    jr $ra         
  numberExtractEnd:    
    jr $ra
```

Comment: `lw $a0, 0($t0)` <-- What's that supposed to do? What do you need the first 4 bytes of the string in a register for?

Comment: `sw $t0, ($v0)` <-- Again, what is that supposed to do? You're not even guaranteed to have initialized `$v0` at that point.

Comment: Yeah so they're supposed to be loading the first value of the string into $a0 and loading the current value of the loop into $v0, respectively

Comment: Your string is made up of byte elements, not words.  `lw` loads *4* bytes, `lbu` loads 1.  And `sw` with an address register that haven't even been set yet won't do whatever it is you wanted it to.

Comment: You need an algorithm.  Try writing a prototype in C, then you can translate to assembly.